# Kubernates autoscaling. ScalingActive False

Tags: kubernetes

Trying  to add autoscaling to my deployment,but getting   `ScalingActive  False`,most answers are about DNS,Heapster,Limits I've done all but still can't find solution.

```
kubectl get hpa
NAME      REFERENCE          TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
fetch     Deployment/fetch   <unknown>/50%   1         4         1          13m


kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at --
addon-http-application-routing-default-http-backend is running at --
addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress is running at --
Heapster is running at  --
KubeDNS is running at --
kubernetes-dashboard is running at --
```

kubectl describe hpa`

[image: kubectl describe hpa]

yaml `

[image: yaml]

PS.I tried to deploy example witch azure provides....getting the same,so yaml settings isn't problem

kubectl describe pod   `

[image: undefined]

kubectl top pod fetch-54f697989d-wczvn --namespace=default`

[image]

autoscaling by memory yaml `

[image]

description`

[image]

`kubectl get hpa` give the same result,unknown/60%

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues, my solutions are setting `resources.requests.cpu` section up in deployment config in order to calculate the current percentage based on the requested resource values. Your event log messages also means not to set up the request resource, but your deployment yaml seems no problem to me too.

Let we do double check as following steps.

If you can verify the resources as following cmd,

```
# kubectl top pod <your pod name> --namespace=<your pod running namespace>
```

And you would also need to check the pod requested cpu resources using below cmd in order to ensure same the config with your deployment yaml.

```
# kubectl describe pod <your pod name>
...
Requests:
  cpu:      250m
...
```

I hope it help you to resolve your issues. ;)

Comment: I've moved resources.requests.cpu under --name,but still getting same errors

Comment: can you check by above `kubectl describe pod` command? It's odd  against your event logs ...

Comment: Requests:
      cpu:  250m

Comment: Would I add all description ?

Comment: Thanks for your information, Can you try to set up the memory in HPA and resources.requests.memory section for test whether it show the memory usage percentage ?

Comment: memory in HPA?How?Added resources.requests.memory,also it is in description

Comment: I've uploaded question and added results

Comment: HPA is defined in the default namespace, and the fetch pod is defined in the same namespaces?

Comment: I've deleted namespace from  yaml and fetch pod is defined in namespace default,so it must be the same

Comment: Could you tried this solution? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57673

Comment: set --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients= true?I coludn't find how can I set it,can you tell ?)

Comment: Wait, your autoscaling api version is lower, as i remember autoscaling/v1 is supported cpu autoscaling. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#api-object

Comment: pod's api version is v1beta1,autoscaling version v2beta1

Comment: What is your version of kubernetes?And this blog show you how to configure the option for hpa, https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-autoscaling-custom-metrics/

Comment: v. 1.10.3.I don't have access to /etc/kubernetes/manifests right now ... so can't edit kube-apiserver.yaml,is there any solution?

Comment: Well, your api version can not implement autoscaling based on cpu, but your kubernetes version is supported v1 api version, so you consider to change api version to v1.

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/318). I just deployed metric server to my cluster and recreated hpa.